# Flutter correct way to handle Future in multiple classes (Google Maps)

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I have a Model class

LocalInfo.dart

```
class LocationInfo {
  // LocationController
  Location location = Location();

  //Location Position Data
  LocationData currentLocation;
  double longitude;
  double latitude;

  LocationInfo() {
    try {
      location.getLocation().then((location) {
        currentLocation = location;
        longitude = currentLocation.longitude;
        latitude = currentLocation.latitude;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      currentLocation = null;
    }
  }
}
```

and my Maps class MapsService.dart

```
MapsService() {
    loading = true;
    locationInfo = LocationInfo(); // <== This takes some time
    cameraPosition = CameraPosition(
        zoom: 15,
        target: LatLng(locationInfo.latitude, locationInfo.longitude)); // <-- Latitude Longitude is null
    loading = false;
  }
```

The problem here is  i create a LocationInfo Model  object which has the longitude and latitude as  class members. But it takes some time to get the values since location.getLocation() returns a Future.

But in my MapsService class i create a LocationInfo object and set the cameraPosition to the given latitude and longitude. But how can i wait for the longitude and latitude value? Long/Lat are null and crash the app because i dont wait.

I need a way in my MapService constructor to wait LocationInfo. It has to finish before i set the Lat and Long value

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use external API in the model. ModelClass is just a Data. You need only initiate subscription in some place of your app and just update the data that connected with your map widget

Ideally, you need something like this:

```
LocationInfo userPosition;
StreamSubscription<LocationData> positionSubscription;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  positionSubscription = location
      .onLocationChanged()
      .handleError((error) => print(error))
      .listen(
        (newPosition) => setState(() {
          _currentLocation = LocationInfo(
            latitude: newPosition.latitude,
            longitude: newPosition.longitude,
          );
        }),
      );
}

@override
void dispose() {
  positionSubscription?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MapWidget(userPosition);
}
```